# why the frequency shift in Spectrogram with different sampling frequency

Tags: signal-processing, sampling, frequency-analysis

I use sensor to measure the vibration of a rotating motor.
use different sampling frequencies 50Hz/100Hz/200Hz/500Hz/1KHz/3KHz/5KHz/8KHz
I found that when I changing the sampling frequency, the peak frequency also shift.
when I using 50Hz sampling frequency, peak frequency is around 3Hz, when I using 100Hz, peak frequency is around 6Hz, when I using 200Hz, peak frequency is around 12Hz.

Can u help me explain why I got this result? I think no matter what sampling frequency used the peak frequency should be the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2v7G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwE7m.png)

Comment: What happens when you sample at higher frequencies?  It superficially looks like aliasing caused by too low of a sample rate.  There are complicated calculations, or turn the knob up until it stabilizes, then trim it back a bit.

Comment: based on the RPM of the motor, 500Hz and above already enough for sampling, but above 1000Hz also got shift...my FFT code is below:
x = np.arange(n, Sampling_Period, n)
y = df.iloc[j]
N = length + 1
fft_y = fft(y) / N

fft_y = 2 * abs(fft_y[range(int(N / 2))])
samples = np.arange(N)
fft_x = samples / Sampling_Period
fft_x = fft_x[range(int(N / 2))]

Comment: Not my expertise; it looks like you are picking up the harmonics of a square wave, and from my elementary dsp understanding, if your base frequency is changing with sampling rate, you aren't sampling fast enough.  Is the mechanical construction such that the vibration of the motor must be less than its operating frequency?  Again, physics isn't exactly my thing either; just a suggestion.